# HiveQL HUE Argument mismatch (Query worked before)

Tags: sql, hive, hue

I got a problem with my query:

```
SELECT
(case when duns_nbr in ('', ' ', '    ') then null else duns_nbr end) as duns_nbr
FROM dl_edge_base_atdsttdp_iidr_data_in. ra9custm
```

I know this query worked like a year ago, but now for some reason it's giving me issues.
I get the next error:
[image]

Any ideas on how this could be fixed?

Comment: this could be an update, that will not let you compare bigint to char

Comment: What is the datatype of duns_nbr? BTW there’s a space before the table name - I assume this is a typo when you wrote the question rather than in your actual SQL

Comment: You should have a constraint rejecting empty strings.

Comment: @nick In HUE you can leave a space and it does not matter. I use it to make it easier to read. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cast to convert duns number to char.

```
SELECT
(case when cast(duns_nbr as string) in ('', ' ', '    ') then null else  cast(duns_nbr as string) end) as duns_nbr
FROM dl_edge_base_atdsttdp_iidr_data_in.ra9custm
```

i think if data type of duns_nbr is `BIGINT`, then this case when is useless and can be removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have not idea how the datatype was changed.